# C# - Get child class type in parent class

Tags: c#

Is it possible to know/get the child class inside parent class? I am using `Autofac` for DI, and `ILogger logger` will be provided by `Autofac`, so `logger` won't be `null` (didn't copy that code here to keep this short)

There are many `child` classes (in a directory), that are inheriting from the `Parent` abstract class. And I would like to do "logger init" once in the parent class (to be DRY). Tried using `this` keyword when I getting `logger.GetCurrentClassLogger<this>()` object, but it seems not right as it won't build.

Here is a sample code -

```cs
public ILogger GetCurrentClassLogger<T>() { return Log.ForContext<T>(); }

public class Parent() {
    protected Serilog.ILogger LoggerDefinedInParentClass;
    public Parent(Serilog.ILogger logger) {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass = logger.GetCurrentClassLogger<Parent>();

        // Hoping to use <Child1> or <Child2> GetCurrentClassLogger<-child class->. Tried <this>, but it might not be right as the build fails
        //
    }

    public void ParentMethod1() {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass.Information("Hello, ParentMethod1");
    }

    public void ParentMethod1() {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass.Information("Hello, ParentMethod2");
    }
}

public class Child1() : Parent {
    public Child1(Serilog.ILogger logger): base(logger) {
    }

    public void ParentMethod1() {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass.Information("Hello, Child1-1");
    }

    public void ParentMethod1() {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass.Information("Hello, Child1-2");
    }
}

public class Child2() : Parent {
    public Child2(Serilog.ILogger logger): base(logger) {
    }

    public void ParentMethod1() {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass.Information("Hello, Child2-1");
    }

    public void ParentMethod1() {
        LoggerDefinedInParentClass.Information("Hello, Child2-2");
    }
}
```

I am hoping to print the log lines as if they are coming from `Child1` or `Child2` child classes, but can't seem to figure it out.

Any ideas anyone? TIA

Comment: I think Serilog has a non generic overload:  `logger.GetCurrentClassLogger(GetType());`

Comment: Child1 and Child2 will inherit the logger defined in Parent. Initializing the logger in the parent is the right way to do it, however, note that both Child1 and Child2 have methods with the same signature as the Parent: ParentMethod1 respectively ParentMethod2. In order to overwrite the methods either use `new` in the children class or make the methods virtual. Otherwise this code `Parent c = new Child1(); c.ParentMethod1()` will use the implementation from the parent, not the child.

Comment: What is `GetCurrentClassLogger`? What version of Serilog are you using?

Comment: @GuruStron added this definition to the post. basically a wrapper for `Serilog.Log.ForContext<>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is non-generic overload of `Log.ForContext` accepting type - you can use it:

```
LoggerDefinedInParentClass = Log.ForContext(this.GetType());
```

Though usual approach is to use the framework-provided `ILogger` and allow the DI handle the injection:

```
public abstract class Parent() {
    public Parent(ILogger logger){...}
}

public class Child1() : Parent {
    public Child1(ILogger<Child1> logger): base(logger) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am after. Works good. Thank you